# Incomplete "File does not exist" Apache error message

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, logging

I have the following problem.

Given the `https://<servername>/apple/` empty directory.
If I refer to `https://<servername>/apple/plum.html` I see this error to appear in the ssl_error_log:

```
[Wed Apr 18 15:13:25 2012] [error] [client ...] 
File does not exist: <DocumentRoot>/apple/plum.html
```

So far so good but if I refer to `https://<servername>/apple/peach/plum.html` (a file in a non-existent peach directory) then I got:

```
[Wed Apr 18 15:13:25 2012] [error] [client ...] 
File does not exist: <DocumentRoot>/apple/peach
```

I would like to see the complete filename in the error log.
The ErrorLogFormat directive in httpd.conf has not been set so the default is used. Anyway the %M parameter (what contains the filename) adds the actual log message in its complete form.

What should I do? I am using Apache 2.2.3 on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64) patch level 3.

Note: The original problem relates to java class loading but I think the above example is more descriptive.

Comment: So this is not, in fact, a problem you are having ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am trying to find the exact name of a java class that apache is searching in the file system before searching it in the jar file. Without the filename I do not know what is missing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be Apache's problem -- the error message being dumped into the error log is coming from your application.  Produce a better error message and Apache will happily relay it to you via the log file :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a not a good solution, only a workaround:

After you receive the error message, create the missing directory. The next time apache will print out a longer error message. If it's still not complete create the subdirectory...